# In Lollipop does the user need to enable security settings for NotificationListenerService

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

All the tutorials for using NotificationListenerService say the user MUST  give explicit permission for the app to listen for notification via Settings | Security |Notification access.

But I don't see Notification access in the Security section on Lollipop. Has it moved somewhere else? If not, then what is the situation regarding using NotificationListenerService in Lollipop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Settings > Sound & notification > Notification access should be what you're looking for on Android 5.x.